# Python on Mac // Changing Working Directory

Tags: python, macos, chdir, cwd

I have been instructed to change the working working directory.  We were provided a file and instructed to put in the Documents folder if we were using a Mac.  I cannot seem to to get it work.

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
Path.cwd()
print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir('/Users/VClark/Documents/cpt180Stuff')
Path.cwd()
print(os.getcwd())
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
/Users/VClark/Desktop/CPT 180
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/VClark/Desktop/CPT 180/workWithFiles.py", line 9, in <module>
    os.chdir('Users/VClark/Documents/cpt180Stuff')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Users/VClark/Documents/cpt180Stuff'
```

Comment: Your error message says you missed off the leading `/`

Comment: I corrected that.  I am still getting an error message when it has the /

Comment: Then the directory probably does not exist at the location you are looking for it.

Comment: did you create this folder ? Python will not create it automatically. OR maybe you created different path - ie. with spaces in name `cpt 180 Stuff`  or with upper case `CPT` ? Maybe check `print( os.list("/Users/VClark/Documents") )`. OR maybe you created it in different folder - if you used path `User/...` without `/` at the beginning then it could create it in `/Users/VClark/Desktop/CPT 180` and maybe you have `/Users/VClark/Desktop/CPT 180/Users/VClark/Documents/cpt180Stuff`

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that in MacOS to use os.chdir() you need to put the directory path in double quotes. Ex. os.chdir("/User/tom").

To change to a directory within the current working directory:
os.chdir("directory_name") -- without the slash.

Comment: I don't think single vs double quotes makes a difference here. It would make one if the paths included special characters like backslashes, but that's not the case here. You're correct about the directories in the current working directory.

Answer (score -1):

When you are dealing with directories, you must always have a "/" at the beginning of the file path, and at the end, indicating the last word is also a folder, or else it will be treated as a file. And you can't change directories to a file. `/Users/hussein/Documents/` is good, `Users/hussein/Documents/` and `/Users/hussein/Documents` are not.

Comment: The trailing slash is not necessary.